# Trouble with Merge Sort

Tags: java, sorting

For my java homework I am struggling to write a recursive merge sort class.  As of right now I have 3 method a "driver" method to start the recursion, the recursive `mergeSort` method and a `merge` method.  Depending on what variables I change my output is either an array of all zeros or my original array in the same order.  The only thing is the original `mergeSort` method must take in one array and the `merge` method cannot return anything. Any help with be much appreciated

```
import java.util.Arrays;
public class merge2 {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        int []a={22,45,1,4,89,7,0};
        mergeSort(a);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(a));                 
    }

    public static void mergeSort(int [] a){
        mergeSort(a,0,a.length-1);
    }

    public static void mergeSort(int []a, int beg,int end){
        if(beg<end){
            int mid=(beg+end)/2;
            mergeSort(a,beg,mid);
            mergeSort(a,mid+1,end);
            merge(a,beg,mid,end);
        }
    }

    private static void merge(int []a, int beg, int middle, int end){
        int [] d=new int[a.length];
        int mid=middle+1; //start of second half of array
        for(int i=0;i<d.length;i++){
            if(beg<=middle && mid<=end){  
                if(a[beg]<=a[mid]) {
                d[i]=a[beg];
                beg++;
                } else if(a[mid]<=a[beg]){
                        d[i]=a[mid];
                        mid++;
                }
            }else if(beg>middle){ 
                d[i]=a[mid];
                mid++;
            }else if(mid==a.length){
                d[i]=a[beg];
                beg++;
            }
        }
        for(int w=0;w<d.length;w++){
            a[w]=d[w];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried stepping through your code in a debugger to see where it seems to go wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I fixed your solution. Your main problem was on line marked with `//<= here`. When `mid` run over end index you were not assigning values from `a` to `d` so it was left filled with `0`. You had to replace `==` with `>=` to overcome this issue.
I also fixed your work with indexes. You don't have to run over whole array on each level. Also your complexity suffers this way. I think its about `O(n^2)`. It's enough to run only over part of array which is processed on this recursion level to keep with `O(nlog(n))` complexity.

Fixed algorithm follows

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    int []a={22,45,1,4,89,7,0};
    mergeSort(a);
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(a));

}

public static void mergeSort(int [] a){
    mergeSort(a,0,a.length-1);
}

public static void mergeSort(int []a, int beg,int end){
    if(beg<end){
        int mid=(beg+end)/2;
        mergeSort(a,beg,mid);
        mergeSort(a,mid+1,end);
        merge(a,beg,mid,end);
    }
}

private static void merge(int []a, int beg, int middle, int end){
    int [] d=new int[a.length];
    int mid=middle+1; //start of second half of array
    int beg1=beg;
    for(int i=beg1;i<=end;i++){
        if(beg<=middle && mid<=end){  
            if(a[beg]<=a[mid]) {
            d[i]=a[beg];
            beg++;
            } else if(a[mid]<=a[beg]){
                    d[i]=a[mid];
                    mid++;
            }
        }else if(beg>middle){         
            d[i]=a[mid];
            mid++;
        }else if(mid>=end){ //<= here
            d[i]=a[beg];
            beg++;
        }
    }
    for(int w=beg1;w<=end;w++){
        a[w]=d[w];
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much.  Worked perfectly.  Once I started to run this on debug mode I realized that I was going through the whole array but not sure what values for it to stop at.

Comment: Can I ask though why at the line marked //<= here why that matters.  I used == because I thought if the mid equaled the end then that half of the array is sorted and the values from beg-middle had to be copied.

Comment: If you reach the upper bound of your array `(mid==end)`, you copy Valu from `a` to `d` and increase mid `mid++` (now `mid==end+1`). But if lower half had larger number than upper half you can't stop here, you also have to copy it. It would be maybe more accurate If there is `(mid==end+1)` instead of `(mid>=end)`.

Answer (score 3):

Here is pseudocode for the mergeSort method. I see that you have disregarded the base cases for one or two elements:

```
if (sublist has only one value)
   do nothing
else if (sublist has two values)
   switch if necessary
else    // recursion, divide list into two halves
   Find midpoint of current sublist
   Call mergeSort and process left sublist
   Call mergeSort and process right sublist
   merge left and right sublists
```

As for your merge method, it is creating a new array instead of modifying the existing array. I suggest using ArrayLists to implement it:

```
private void merge(int[] a, int first, int mid, int last)
  {
    ArrayList<Integer> left = new ArrayList<Integer>(mid - first + 1), right = new ArrayList<Integer>(last - mid);
    for(int m = first; m <= mid; ++m)   //initialize left sublist
    {
      left.add(a[m]);
    }
    for(int m = mid + 1; m <= last; ++m)    //initialize right sublist
    {
      right.add(a[m]);
    }
    int i = first;
    while(!left.isEmpty() || !right.isEmpty())  //while either list has an element
    {
      if(left.isEmpty())
      {
        a[i++] = right.remove(0);
      }
      else if(right.isEmpty())
      {
        a[i++] = left.remove(0);
      }
      else if (left.get(0) < right.get(0))
      {
        a[i++] = left.remove(0);
      }
      else
      {
        a[i++] = right.remove(0);
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: +1 for anyone who is willing to dig into an implementation of merge sort.

Comment: Thanks, i altered my mergeSort method to work with your pseudocode and your merge method, when I run this i get a stackoverflowerror.  I forgot to mention we can't use an arraylist but i can modify that